# infile .csv file in sas with header

Tags: sas, load-data-infile

I have a csv file which named dataset1.csv and it contains header with 3 variables att1 (character), att2 and att3 (numeric data).

I tried following code

```
filename test 'C:\Users\1502911\Desktop\Practice\SAS\Dataset';

data dataset1;
    infile test(dataset1.csv) dsd delimiter=',';
    input att1 $ att2 att3;
run;
```

[image]

My desired output is to ignore first row

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `firstobs` option in `infile` statement, which would make sure you read the data from second row

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/67407/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm

```
data dataset1;
    infile test(dataset1.csv) dsd delimiter=',' firstobs=2;
    input att1 $ att2 att3;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `proc import` is much more convenient, you don't need to manually assign the column name

```
/** FOR CSV Files uploaded from Unix/MacOS **/
FILENAME CSV "/folders/myfolders/train.csv" TERMSTR=LF;

/** Import the CSV file.  **/
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=CSV
            OUT=WORK.MYCSV
            DBMS=CSV
            REPLACE;
run;

/** Print the results. **/
PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.MYCSV; RUN;

/** Unassign the file reference.  **/
FILENAME CSV;
run;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why the "unassign the file reference" code is needed?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember. I haven' used SAS since I gave that answer.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for replying :D